# Ajax How to load ajax div into another ajax div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a Main.php. Inside Main.php I have a div that i load my main pages into such as home.html, info.html, product.php, contact.php, etc.

I am in the process of making my info.html and inside info.html i want to make another div that i load content from other pages into. In the same way i have done it in Main.php.

However this I can't get to work. It won't load content into info.html

I load my content like this in Javascript

```
$("#LoadDiv").load("InfoLogo.html");
```

Anyone know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Simply change info.html and InfoLogo.html to info.php and InfoLogo.php

then do a require function inside info.php like this:

```
require "InfoLogo.php";
```

and then it will load the content into Info.php which is already loaded into Main.php